# How do you convert a custom-item /give command into a villager trade? (in general)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I know this is similar to many other questions out there, but I just wanted to ask not only how to convert a custom-made item into a villager trade, but also if there is a general way to convert said items into trades simply by tweaking parts of the command.

When I say "custom-made item", I am referring to **items that have a custom name, custom lore, and optionally also custom enchants, HideFlags, the Unbreakable tag, and modifiers.** I am only focusing on items that have these things, nothing else. Additionally, I will only be focusing on vanilla singleplayer 1.14. This is an example item showing what a custom item will have.

[image]

`/give @p minecraft:coarse_dirt{display:{Name:'{"text":"Example name","color":"gold","bold":true,"italic":true}',Lore:['{"text":"Example lore","color":"dark_aqua","bold":false,"italic":true,"underlined":true}','{"text":"This item has the Unbreakable tag and a custom modifier.","color":"aqua"}']},Unbreakable:1b,Enchantments:[{id:"minecraft:protection",lvl:10s}],AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:0.01,Operation:1,UUIDLeast:961281,UUIDMost:716413,Slot:"mainhand"}]} 1`

Essentially, I have made a /give command that gives me a villager spawn egg who has a custom name, custom lore, the Unbreakable tag, and an enchantment / HideFlag for enchants to make the item have a "glow effect". This villager then also has one trade, where it trades a "custom item" for a different "custom item". After making it in MCStacker and testing it in a creative vanilla 1.14 world, you can see that the command is 100% working.

[image]
[image]
[image]

The only things that I have specified otherwise for this trader are its profession, what biome variant it is, and its level.

**Pastebin link to command:** https://pastebin.com/uX9tVzc2

I made this in MCStacker, so you can see what the command has by copying the command from the Pastebin, then go to [this link](https://mcstacker.net/1.14.php), Import > paste the command in > hit Import again.

How could I make this /give command into a tradable item in a trader? I've tried pasting everything after "/give @p" into a trade command, but it wasn't working. Do I need to add "tag:" or something else to make it work? Or will I have to completely remake the villager spawn egg as a trade instead for it to work in a trader?

Comment: Very well-stated question, but nevertheless a duplicate.

Comment: I'll check it out, I initially thought that question was only focused on well, spawning a chest, but I will give it a look.

Comment: The question is a duplicate because it also requires the use of the `tag` compound NBT tag.

Comment: @pppery That makes it a good duplicate, those are the reason why duplicates are not deleted. Using different words for the same problem makes the solution easier to find for others.